# How to have meld as git mergetool to only show conflict and not differences?

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict, meld

When I use meld as `git mergetool` for solving conflict while merging, meld shows me the differences between local/output and remote/output files (in blue or green) that git automatically solves, and not only the actual conflicts (that are red highlighted). And when I click on the down arrow, it goes to the next (blue/green) difference, and not to the next conflict (red). In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501666/why-does-git-mergetool-meld-show-conflict-markers) topic, a picture illustrates this.

How could I

- ignore the difference that are not conflict
- or go to the next conflict (like in kdiff3), without stopping on the differences
  ??

Comment: I really like using meld with git mergetool, but I too only want to see the conflicts.

Answer (score 11):

Add the following to your `.gitconfig`:

```
[mergetool "meld"]
  cmd = meld --auto-merge "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE" --output "$MERGED"
```

This is the same command Git runs by default with `--auto-merge` specified so that Meld automatically resolves what it can.

Comment: Found that this option does not work well with `git difftool --tool=meld -d`. It fails with `Error: --output option requires 1 argument`.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to meld-specific parameters, you now have new Git options:

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), "[`git mergetool`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/78a26cb7204ddb96a5f75f09e41fbefd81c85f59/Documentation/git-mergetool.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool))</sup> feeds three versions (base, local and remote) of a conflicted path unmodified.
The command learned to optionally prepare these files with **unconflicted parts already resolved**.

See [commit 9d9cf23](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d9cf230317f7fe7cb153f61b537e6e9bef22e3b), [commit de8dafb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/de8dafbada811bc1bc8e1288541931f3c5406231), [commit 98ea309](https://github.com/git/git/commit/98ea309b3fa4818c1591b9071925ccb22c2e786b) (09 Feb 2021) by [Seth House (`whiteinge`)](https://github.com/whiteinge).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 78a26cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/78a26cb7204ddb96a5f75f09e41fbefd81c85f59), 17 Feb 2021)</sup>

> ### [`mergetool`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/98ea309b3fa4818c1591b9071925ccb22c2e786b): add `hideResolved` configuration
>
> <sup>Original-implementation-by: Felipe Contreras</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Seth House</sup>

> The purpose of a mergetool is to help the user resolve any conflicts that Git cannot automatically resolve.
> If there is a conflict that must be resolved manually Git will write a file named MERGED which contains everything Git was able to resolve by itself and also everything that it was not able to resolve wrapped in conflict markers.
>
> One way to think of `MERGED` is as a two- or three-way diff.
> If each "side" of the conflict markers is separately extracted an external tool can represent those conflicts as a side-by-side diff.
>
> However many mergetools instead diff `LOCAL` and `REMOTE` both of which contain versions of the file from before the merge.
> Since the conflicts Git resolved automatically are not present it forces the user to manually re-resolve those conflicts.
> Some mergetools also show `MERGED` but often only for reference and not as the focal point to resolve the conflicts.
>
> This adds a `mergetool.hideResolved` flag that will overwrite `LOCAL` and `REMOTE` with each corresponding "side" of a conflicted file and thus hide all conflicts that Git was able to resolve itself.
> Overwriting these files will immediately benefit any mergetool that uses them without requiring any changes to the tool.
>
> No adverse effects were noted in a [small survey of popular mergetools](https://www.eseth.org/2020/mergetools.html) so this behavior defaults to `true`.
> However it can be globally disabled by setting `mergetool.hideResolved` to `false`.

See "[Mergetools: Stop doing three-way merges!](https://github.com/whiteinge/eseth/blob/c884424769fffb05d87afb33b2cf80cecb4044c3/2020/mergetools.md)"

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/98ea309b3fa4818c1591b9071925ccb22c2e786b/Documentation/config/mergetool.txt#L43-L52):

> ### `mergetool.hideResolved`
>
> During a merge Git will automatically resolve as many conflicts as
> possible and write the 'MERGED' file containing conflict markers around
> any conflicts that it cannot resolve; 'LOCAL' and 'REMOTE' normally
> represent the versions of the file from before Git's conflict
> resolution.
>
> This flag causes 'LOCAL' and 'REMOTE' to be overwriten so
> that only the unresolved conflicts are presented to the merge tool.
>
> Can
> be configured per-tool via the `mergetool.<tool>.hideResolved`
> configuration variable. Defaults to `true`.

In the OP's case:

```
git config --global mergetool.meld.hideResolved true
```

This is described in:

> ### [`mergetool`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d9cf230317f7fe7cb153f61b537e6e9bef22e3b): add per-tool support and overrides for the hideResolved flag
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Johannes Sixt</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Seth House</sup>

> Add a per-tool override flag so that users may enable the flag for one tool and disable it for another by setting `mergetool.<tool>.hideResolved` to `false`.
>
> In addition, the author or maintainer of a mergetool may optionally override the default `hideResolved` value for that mergetool.
> If the `mergetools/<tool>` shell script contains a `hide_resolved_enabled` function it will be called when the mergetool is invoked and the return value will be used as the default for the `hideResolved` flag.
>
> ```
> hide_resolved_enabled () {
>     return 1
> }
> ```
>
> Disabling may be desirable if the mergetool wants or needs access to the original, unmodified 'LOCAL' and 'REMOTE' versions of the conflicted file.
>
> For example:
>
> - A tool may use a custom conflict resolution algorithm and prefer to ignore the results of Git's conflict resolution.
> - A tool may want to visually compare/constrast the version of the file from before the merge (saved to 'LOCAL', 'REMOTE', and 'BASE') with Git's conflict resolution results (saved to 'MERGED').

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9d9cf230317f7fe7cb153f61b537e6e9bef22e3b/Documentation/config/mergetool.txt#L16-L20):

> ### `mergetool.<tool>.hideResolved`
>
> Allows the user to override the global `mergetool.hideResolved` value
> for a specific tool.

Answer (score 7):

In meld, you can click Changes > Merge All, which will merge most changes except for the conflicts.

Comment: This seems to do nothing for me. `meld 3.14.0`

Comment: If you are using 'xxdiff', the option is "Global->Merge". Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

If you use cmd+D in your mac it will got to the next conflict, no matter how many changes it is showing. Or in the menu go to Find -> Go Next -> Conflict